# SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: node.js

After install node.js and start using it, here is the problem, what should I do?

```
Administrator@USER-OFRATV7Q0V MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ node
> C:\workspace>server.js
C:\workspace>server.js
  ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: Running node enters its [REPL mode](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/repl.html#repl_the_node_js_repl) and so you have to enter Javascript code there. `C:\workspace>server.js` ain't no Javascript ...

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want to do is launch the script you wrote. To do that on Windows, you execute :

```
C:\Workspace>nodejs server.js
```

Or

```
C:\Workspace>node server.js
```

Depending on your node version.